# Sql и Vba, запрос для listbox

Tags: access, vba, sql

Привет вам.
пишу для listbox в vba запрос

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim TextSQL As String

TextSQL = "SELECT Рота.CompanyID, Рота.Battalion, Рота.Commander2, Рота.Rank3, Рота.Passport, Рота.Photo2" & _
            "FROM Рота" & _
            "WHERE Рота.Battalion='Батальон_1'"
Me.Список35.RowSource = TextSQL

End Sub
```

а он меня игнорит - выводит 0 записей(вместо одной), в чем беда?

Ps пробовал Батальон_1 и с '' и без, не робит.

Answer (score 3):

Поставьте пробел перед FROM и перед WHERE.
Если работать не будет, проверьте, работает ли запрос в конструкторе.